# How does OAuth work API to API without interactive users?

Tags: api, http, oauth-2.0

I have a background task that runs periodically which needs to connect to a customer's Apigee OAuth2 protected API. From my understanding of OAuth2, a user must go to a sign in page on Apigee, and it will redirect to a return Url with a token. This is the way I have used previously on website projects.  But in this scenario, there are no users, no website, and no return Url, it is just some code making a http request.

Is the above possible to do? Every google search I make is all about users logging in manually and getting a token to a return url.

I found some mention of 'Flows' and maybe there is some other 'Flow'? but its really hard to get a clear understanding of how it works because guides are focused on user interactive websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAUTH 2.0 is an industry-standard for authorization. OAUTH 2.0 supports many authorization grant types, namely they are;

1. Authorization Code
2. Implicit
3. Resource Owner Password Credentials
4. Client Credentials
   [Note that you may come up with your own custom grants as well if you are building or extending your authorization server - however it is beyond the scope of this question]

In the example you have provided, you are using the Authorization code grant type where you redirect to APIGEE and getting an authorization code. The APIGE server acts as the "intermediary between the client and resource owner" in OAUTH 2.0 terms.

For your new requirement, you should consider using the client-credentials grant type where the client is provided a client key and a secret. The client has the responsibility of calling the authorization server (like APIGEE in your previous example or anything else) and getting a token and then using that token in the subsequent requests.

I recommend you to read the ietf standard for oauth 2.0 to get a better understanding - Refer https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749.
Make sure to read on "Roles" in this link well before diving onto the content of this document.
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. This was the answer I needed.